# Intersection of weighted Sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, embeddings

Consider the Sobolev spaces with $p=2$, defined for $s \in \mathbb{R}$ as
\begin{equation}
W^{s} = \left\{ u \in \mathcal{S}', \ (1 + \lvert \cdot \rvert^2)^{{s}/{2}} \widehat{u} \in L_2  \right\}.
\end{equation}
It is a Hilbert space for the norm $\lVert u \rVert_{W^s} = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}  (1 + \lvert \xi \rvert^2)^s \lvert \widehat{u} (\xi) \rvert^2 \mathrm{d} \xi \right)^{1/2}$.

The weighted Sobolev space $W^{s,r}$ is now defined for $s,r \in \mathbb{R}$ as
\begin{equation}
W^{s,r} = \left\{ u \in \mathcal{S}', \ (1 + \lvert \cdot \rvert^2)^{{r}/{2}} u \in W^s  \right\}.
\end{equation}
Again, it is a Hilbert space for the norm $\lVert u \rVert_{W^{s,r}} = \lVert (1 + \lvert \cdot \rvert^2)^{{r}/{2}} u \rVert_{W^s}$.

We have the obvious embeddings, for $s_1 \leq s_2$ and $r_1 \leq r_2$, 
\begin{align}
W^{s_2,r} \subseteq W^{s_1,r}, \\
W^{s,r_2} \subseteq W^{s,r_1}.
\end{align}

Now, is the following result true?

**Conjecture:**
Fix $s_1, s_2, r_1, r_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Then,
\begin{equation}
W^{s_1,r_1} \cap W^{s_2,r_2} = W^{\max(s_1,s_2),\max(r_1,r_2)}.
\end{equation}

Of course, due to the embeddings above, $W^{\max(s_1,s_2),\max(r_1,r_2)}$ is included in $W^{s_1,r_1}$ and $W^{s_2,r_2}$ and therefore in their intersection. Is the other inclusion also valid?

Comment: I don't think so. For a wave packet of frequency $F$, amplitude $A$, and spatial position $X$, the $W^{s,r}$ norm goes like $F^s X^r A$. So it seems possible to arrange $F_n, X_n, A_n$ such that $$ \sum F^{s_1}_n X^{r_1}_n A_n < \infty, \qquad \sum F^{s_2}_n X^{r_2}_n A_n < \infty $$ while $$ \sum F^{s_2}_n X^{r_1}_n A_n $$ diverge.

Comment: Elaborating the above comment, let $s_1=0$, $r_1=1$, $s_2=1$, $r_2=0$, $F_n=X_n=n$ and $A_n=n^{-3}$.